# On CentOS, how do you make the exception for x-debug permanent

Tags: netbeans, centos, xdebug

I'm not sure if this is more of a sysadmin question but in order to use x-debug, I have to run the following from my terminal everytime I boot up the machine.

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Does anyone know how I can make this permanent so that I don't have to run this command everytime I start my machine?

Thank you.

----EDIT----

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Now I can debug as soon as the machine boots thanks to Ulrich Schmidt-Goertz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the command with the `-P` flag. That should make the setting permanent.